# MVC4 Razor difference in @model and @inherit in view header?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

To make a view strongly typed we can use `@model` and `@inherit`. Can you please tell me what the difference is between both of them?

Edit:

Please see [this example](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-best-practices-keep-logic-out-of-your-razor-views/).

Comment: Wow! @inherit! Just in time! Thanks; I do not know the answer; but your question was my answer! :)

Answer (score 32):

The difference is as follows: if your view inherits from `WebViewPage<T>` then your model directive points to `T`.

In other words, these two are equivalent

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<ModelClass>
```

and

```
@model ModelClass
```

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Comment: does it means @@inherits only work with System.Web.Mvc.WebviwPage<T> ? and with @@model we are free to chose class ?

Comment: @user576510: `@model` also means that page inherits from `WebViewPage`. What you specify is the generic parameter.

Comment: The `@model` directive was not working because I have my views in a separate project using a custom virtual provider.  The `@inherits` worked like a charm and solved hours or internet digging.  Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 6):

They are the same (i.e. indicate strongly-typed model classes) but `@inherit` is more verbose (because of the full path). `@inherit` was the only way to do it when razor was first introduced (pre-release of MVC 3 I think), but I haven't seen it used for years.

Comment: I got it but the thing is why they need to introduce @@model ? I cant believe both do same thing.

Comment: The link in Wiktor's answer explains it better that I could.