# MVC 6 @inherit RazorPage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to migrate an MVC 5 Application to ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (Beta 7).
Having problems when using the `@inherits` and `@model` directive together.
Works fine when they are used separately.

In my `_ViewImports` i added the `@inherits` directive to use a base page with some custom user properties.

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    protected MyPrincipal AppUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyPrincipal(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshttml

```
@inherits CommonWeb.BaseViewPage<TModel>
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

And then i can go **AppUser.** in all my views.
This works if i **dont** use a strongly typed view. If i add the `@model` directive in any view the inherited view page goes away.

Help appreciated

**Update:**

I did this successfully by using a custom *pageBaseType* in the web.config in prior versions.

Workaround.

```
public class ViewHelper
{
    ViewContext _context;

    public ViewHelper(ViewContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public MyPrincipal AppUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyPrincipal(_context.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }

    public string ControllerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{ var viewHelper = new ViewHelper(ViewContext);}
```

A way to achieve this for all views?

Comment: you cant use both at the same time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854556/mvc4-razor-difference-in-model-and-inherit-in-view-header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way in MVC 6, which now supports [injecting dependencies](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#inj) on the views with the `@inject` directive. (The directive `@inject IFoo Foo` allows you to use in your view a property named `Foo` of type `IFoo`)

Create a new interface `IAppUserAccessor` for getting your app user, for example:

```
public interface IAppUserAccessor
{
    MyPrincipal GetAppUser();
}
```

Create a class `AppUserAccessor` implementing it:

```
public class AppUserAccessor : IAppUserAccessor
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextProvider;
    public AppUserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextProvider)
    {
        this.httpContextProvider = httpContextProvider;
    }

    public MyPrincipal GetAppUser()
    {
        return new MyPrincipal (
                       httpContextProvider.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal);            
    }
}
```

Register the new interface in the services container by adding a new entry in the `ConfigureServices` method of **Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddTransient<IAppUserAccessor, AppUserAccessor>();
```

Finally use the `@inject` directive to inject the `IAppUserAccessor` in your views. **If you add the directive in `ViewImports.cshtml` then it will be available on every view**.

```
@inject WebApplication4.Services.IAppUserAccessor AppUserAccessor
```

With all the pieces above you can now just use it on your view(s):

```
@AppUserAccessor.GetAppUser()
```

**Update**

If you need to inspect the route values, like the controller name, you can inject an `IActionContextAccessor` into your class and use it as follows:

```
public AppUserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextProvider, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
{
    this.httpContextProvider = httpContextProvider;
    this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
}

...

public string ControllerName
{
    get { return actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(); }            
}
```

Of course, that doesn't look like an `AppUserAccessor` anymore and smells like it has different responsabilities. At the very least it needs a more appropriate name :)

I would double check what do I need the controller name for. There might be a better way to accomplish your objective. (For example, if you need it for generating new links/urls you might just use an `IUrlHelper`)

**Accessing ViewContext**

Looks like beta8 has added support for injecting the ViewContext, although the implementation details may change before RC. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892264/how-access-viewcontext-from-helper-service-injected-via-viewimports)

Comment: Thank you @daniel-j-g that is so much cleaner! Almost there now! I need the ViewContext for Route values etc.. Cant figure out to inject that.

Comment: You already have the ViewContext available in every view, using `@ViewContext`

Comment: @daniel-j-g Yes, but then i have to new up my ViewHelper in every view like i am doing now right? It would be nice to have the ViewContext injected so i can get a hold of routes to populate my ControllerName and ActionName properties etc (See my update). I cant get that through the plain HttpContext i think?

Comment: I am not aware of any `ViewContextAccessor` and you can't just add a new `ViewContext` dependency to your constructor because the framework won't know how to resolve it. What do you need it for? If it is for creating new links/urls or access the current url (but not the current route values) then you could add a dependency for `IUrlHelper` to your helper. You could also create extension methods that could be used in your view

Comment: Actually, I have just realized that you can inject an `IActionContextAccessor` into your class, and use it to get the route values (including the controller name) as in `actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`. Will update the answer

Comment: Perfect!! Now it is working exactly how i want. Thank you very much! @daniel-j-g

Comment: Excellent @Fredde. By the way, you can upvote the answer if it was of help to you :)

Comment: For sure, as soon as possible. Not enough reputation to vote yet. I am new on SO. @daniel-j-g