# How access ViewContext from helper/service, @injected via ViewImports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing helper class and inject in in `_ViewImports` with

```
@inject HtmlHelperInject.TestHelper TestHelper
```

And register in `Startup.ConfigureServices` with

```
services.AddTransient<TestHelper>();
```

How can I obtain `ViewContext` in this helper class? I tried injecting via controler - not working, via `[ViewContext]` attribute on property - not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of right now (beta8) the way to do this is to implement... wait for it... `ICanHasViewContext`. This interface adds the following contract:

```
void Contextualize(ViewContext viewContext);
```

When injecting your custom utility MVC calls `Contextualize` and passes in the current `ViewContext`. Note: this mechanism will most likely change in future releases. If not, the name certainly will :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! BTW, this interface exists in beta7 too.

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this, it was renamed to `IViewContextAware` before release to 1.0.