# Single .NET Core Razor C# functions in all Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know there is a way to ad c# functions inside a view and call them by using `@functions{ ... }` method inside my view, but is there a way to create a shared view with those functions to include inside of the controllers view without copying the same line of code on each one? I tried by using `@inject` and other methods inside the `_Layout` view, but obviously those methods can't be called. I also tried to create an external class like this, but I want to use views only if it is possible:

```
public class Functions : RazorPage<dynamic>
{
    public override Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetTabActive(string lang)
    {
        if (ViewBag.lang.ToString() == lang) return "active";
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes do this in your controller! True MVC (not Microsoft's interpretation of it) says no logic should ever be in the view (a views job is to render the view model, no more). This is a good reason why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this, i needed to inject the class inside of the `_ViewImports` giving a property name, like so:

```
@inject Functions func
```

And, in the `StartUp`, i added a new service pointing to my abstract class like that:

```
services.AddSingleton<Functions>();
```

So, inside each view, i can use models and call my functions like that:

```
<h2>@func.MyFunction</h2>
```

Comment: This isn't the same, though - in a `.cshtml` page, code in the `@functions` block has full access to the current `RazorPage` instance via `this`, but in your approach the `Functions` class has no access to that data at all, requiring it all to be passed as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Create an abstract class that inherits WebViewPage

```
public abstract class TestView<TViewModel> : WebViewPage<TViewModel>
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

In your views use "Inherits"

```
@inherits TestView<dynamic>
```

Your method will be available

```
@TestMethod()
```

--Side note

You should not use @model in conjunction with @inherits
You just want one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did it and it seems to work. The only problem is that '@Html.TextBox(..)' gives me some error when using inherits

Comment: Hey - I have updated my answer so you can pass the model type. Hopefully that is enough to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks from me too, I never knew this was possible. On further research I can also recommend this answer (and the link that it contains): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23854627/1220550

Comment: Thank you @MichaelLake for the help, is there any way to use the '@inject' instead of the inherit? Because i don't want to change all my views, because i'm using a model on each. I tried by myself with the inject and creating an abstract object, but it gives me an error because i did not included it on my services on the startup. Any tips for that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few approaches:

### Approach 1: Subclass `RazorPage<TModel>`

You can (ab)use OOP inheritance to add common members (i.e. methods/functions, but also properties) to your Razor page types by subclassing `RazorPage<T>` and updating all of your pages to use your new subclass as their base type instead of defaulting to ASP.NET Core's `RazorPage` or `RazorPage<TModel>`.

1. In your project, subclass `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>`, e.g. `class MyPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>`
2. Add whatever methods you like (`protected` or `public`, and `static` or instance all work).
3. In all `.cshtml` files where you want to use them, change your `@model MyPageModel` directive to `@inherits MyPage<MyPageModel>`.

Note that:

- The `class RazorPage<TModel>` derives from the (non-generic) `class RazorPage` class, so subclassing `RazorPage<TModel>` will *not* cause those members to be visible from pages deriving from `RazorPage`.

  - Note that if your `.cshtml` lacks a `@model` directive, the actual page class will derive from `RazorPage<dynamic>` instead of `RazorPage`.
- You can, of course, subclass `RazorPage<TModel>` with a non-generic class provided you specify a concrete type for `TModel` in your subclass; this is useful when you have multiple `.cshtml` pages that share the same `@model` type and need lots of custom C# logic.

For example:

**MyPage.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace MyProject
{
    public abstract class MyPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
    {
        protected String Foobar()
        {
            return "Lorem ipsum";
        }
    }
}
```

**ActualPage.cshtml**:

```
@using MyProject // <-- Or import in your _ViewImports
@inherits MyPage<ActualPageViewModel>

<div>
    @( this.Foobar() )  <!-- Function is inherited -->
</div>
```

That said, I'm not a super-huge fan of this approach because (in my opinion) subclassing and inheritance should not be abused as a substitute for mixins (though I appreciate that C#'s lack of mixins is a huge ergonomic issue).

### Approach 2: Extension methods

- You can also define extension methods for `RazorPage` and `RazorPage<TModel>`, but also for *specific `TModel` types*.

  - You could also define them for `IRazorPage` or `RazorPageBase` if you really wanted to as well.
  - This is the closest thing we have in C# to *generic specialization*.
  - When extending `RazorPage<TModel>` - and you don't care about `TModel`, then make it generic type-parameter on your extension-method (see `Foobar2` in my example below).
- C# extension methods require `this.` to be used, btw.
- And don't forget to import the extension class' namespace (either in the page with `@using` or in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file).
- Note th

For example:

**MyPageExtensions.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class MyPageExtensions
    {
        public static String Foobar1( this RazorPage page )
        {
            return "Lorem ipsum";
        }

        public static String Foobar2<TModel>( this RazorPage<TModel> page )
        {
            return "Lorem ipsum";
        }
    }
}
```

**ActualPage.cshtml**:

```
@using MyProject // <-- Or import in your _ViewImports
@model ActualPageViewModel

<div>
    @( this.Foobar() )  <!-- Extension Method -->
</div>
```

### Getting `IHtmlHelper`, `IUrlHelper`, etc.

You might notice that `RazorPage<TModel>` does not have `IHtmlHelper Html { get; }` nor `IUrlHelper Url { get; }` properties - nor other useful ASP.NET MVC-specific members. That's because those members are only defined in the hidden `PageName.cshtml.g.cs` file's class (it's in your `obj\$(Configuration)\$(TargetPlatform)\Razor\...` directory, if your project builds okay).

In order to get access to those members you can define an interface to expose those properties, and you can direct ASP.NET Core to add that interface to the `.cshtml.g.cs` classes by adding `@implements` to your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

This is what I use in my projects:

**IRazorPageInjectedProperties.cs**:

```cs
public interface IRazorPageInjectedProperties
{
    ViewContext ViewContext { get; }

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelMetadataProvider   ModelMetadataProvider   { get; }
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; }
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper                            Url                     { get; }
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper                  Component               { get; }
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IJsonHelper                 Json                    { get; }
//  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper                 Html                    { get; }

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper                 HtmlHelper              { get; }
}
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml**:

```
@using System
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
@* etc *@
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelMetadataProvider ModelMetadataProvider
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper               HtmlHelper

@implements MyProject.IRazorPageInjectedProperties
```

The `IHtmlHelper` type needs an explicit `@inject` directive because `interface` members have to be `public` (or explicit interface implementations), but the `Html` property is `protected`, but `@inject` members are `public`. The name needs to be `HtmlHelper` instead of `Html` otherwise it would conflict.

**If subclassing `RazorPage`** you might notice your subclass can't really implement `IRazorPageInjectedProperties` because you'd need to add the properties there (as `abstract`), but `@inject` properties won't `override` them, but you could hack it a bit with some indirect properties, like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace MyProject
{
    public abstract class MyPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
    {
        private IRazorPageInjectedProperties Self => (IRazorPageInjectedProperties)this;

        private IHtmlHelper Html => this.Self.HtmlHelper;
        private IUrlHelper  Url  => this.Self.Url;

        protected IHtmlContent GetAHrefHtml()
        {
            return this.Html.ActionLink( ... );
        }

        protected String GetHrefUrl()
        {
            return this.Url.Action( ... );
        }
    }
}
```

**If using extension-methods** you'll need to either:

- Modify `IRazorPageInjectedProperties` to extend `IRazorPage` and make `IRazorPageInjectedProperties` the target of your extension-methods.

  - See `GetAHrefHtml` in the example below.
- or change your extension methods to be generic over `TPage : RazorPage` add a type-constraint to require `IRazorPageInjectedProperties`.

  - See `GetHrefUrl1` in the example below.
- to get `TModel` you'll need to make the extensions generic over `TPage` *and* `TModel` *with* `IRazorPageInjectedProperties`.

  - See `GetHrefUrl2` in the example below.

**MyPageExtensions.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

namespace MyProject
{
    public interface IRazorPageInjectedProperties : IRazorPage
    {
        // etc
    }

    public static class MyPageExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent GetAHrefHtml( this IRazorPageInjectedProperties page )
        {
            return page.Html.ActionLink( ... );
        }

        public static String GetHrefUrl1<TPage>( this TPage page )
            where TPage : RazorPage, IRazorPageInjectedProperties
        {
            return page.Url.Action( ... );
        }

        // to get TModel:

        public static String GetHrefUrl2<TPage,TModel>( this TPage page )
            where TPage : RazorPage<TModel>, IRazorPageInjectedProperties
        {
            return page.Url.Action( ... );
        }
    }
}
```